# Can i change blogger post preview url?

Tags: blogger, adsense

Today i got a warning from Google Adsense "There are unauthorized sites that have displayed ads using your AdSense publisher ID within the last week. Please click here..." etc.

I have added my all websites in my adsense authorization page & currently site authorization is active.

After search in the adsense pageview page, finally i got the url

i.e.
I have a blogger blog & added a custom domain.
Before publish the post i click on the preview button, then open new tab & its show the post preview.

But the preview url is like this
https://4492560067822442951_1ad60e48051667999.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=3f6aj1fsdfwBAAA.OWl1PrgJZ9iqxEsdfstTU1BW_o8AyE74KVOyWmRglY4gv4FQY_1NyNWdqorJqaSEDaIKvsw7BhLgz2JpAJc7f23_Tw.T3lperu4WH_zIQFxVgfEpA&postId=60302242414450751984379&type=POST

I already seen that this url in adsense page view list. I think this is reason for adsense warning.

I had tried to add this domain **4492560067822442951_1ad60e1667999.blogspot.com** in adsense authorization page. But invalid url error occured.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: yes sure. you can make sure ad not load on certain domain like that (preview). First of all, where you placed your adsense ad codes? HTML Template or sidebar widget? both can solved. but please provide your Template HTML. So i can give a example code to base on your Template structure codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing your ads from displaying on the Preview Pages should be able to solve this problem. Blogger provides a data layout tag ([data:view.isPreview](http://template-data.blogspot.com/2017/03/ispreview_16.html)) which can find if the page opened is a preview page or not. You will have to wrap your ad code present in theme within it so that the ads will not be rendered on preview pages. The sample code will look like -

```
<b:if cond='!data:view.isPreview'> 
    <!-- Your Ad Code -->
</b:if>
```